# Looping through cells adding content

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, loops

In the an application I'm working on it should be possible to dynamically add numbers to cells in a table. The user types for example nr 1, and then the number should increment by 1 in each cell (eg. cell1 = 1, cell2 = 2, cell3 = 3 and so on).

I guess I can use either a for-loop or a for-each loop, but what I need to know is how to step through the cells and adding new content to each of them?

By the way. I am using the Table Control (not "pure HTML"), and the table contains of 7 rows and two cols. I want it to loop through the cells as following:

---

### :   1     :     2   :

### :   3     :     4   :

### :   5     :     6   :

and so on...

Comment: what type of table / cells are we talking about.. ASPNET Tables GridView, Excel etc... define what table / cell structure you are dealing with and for cells / rows you will need to do nested for loop but I am sure there are other ways as well

Comment: You should use a for-loop in this case. For-each is for cycling automatically through a specific set, iterating each single element. But as you want to use your cell-index in correlation to your cell-content you need to use the same counting-variable. Just do a for-i-loop, beginning at 1, ending at the last cell-index you want to change and do a i++ or i+=1 in each iteration. Then use `cell[i] = i * userinput` or something to set your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreach like like this should do the trick:

```
int yourStartInt = 6;

foreach(Control control in YourTableID.Controls)
{
    if (control is TableRow)
    {
        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (innerControl != null && innerControl is TableCell)
            {
                TableCell cell = innerControl as TableCell;
                cell.Text = yourStartInt.ToString();
                yourStartInt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You must loop through your table's controls to find the rows, and then in the rows you can find the cells in similar fashion.